# Linux allocation pointer values and performance

Tags: linux, performance, pointers, memory-management, malloc

I'm a bit puzzled by allocation on linux ( RedHat 5 and 6 , running on intel / amd cpu is the same) and their related performance.
Here's a simple code that allocates and free a double array, just looking at the address value. Allocation from 0 to 256Mb, by chunk of 1 Kb.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc , char ** argv )
{
#define ASZ 33661057   

  size_t len ;

  double * ptr ;

  for ( len = 128 ; len < ASZ ; len += 128  )
  {
    ptr = malloc( len ) ;
    printf( "ptr addr : %p len %12ld %8.1f Kb\n" , ptr , len , ( (double ) len ) * 8. / 1024. ) ;
    free( ptr ) ;
  }

  return( 0 ) ;
}
```

Here is some output of this program:

```
ptr addr : 0xadb010 len          128      1.0 Kb
ptr addr : 0xadb010 len          256      2.0 Kb
ptr addr : 0xadb010 len       135040   1055.0 Kb
ptr addr : 0x2ab1eef4c010 len       135168   1056.0 Kb
ptr addr : 0xadb010 len       135296   1057.0 Kb
ptr addr : 0xadb010 len       270208   2111.0 Kb
ptr addr : 0x2ab1eef4c010 len       270336   2112.0 Kb
ptr addr : 0xadb010 len       270464   2113.0 Kb
ptr addr : 0xadb010 len       405376   3167.0 Kb
ptr addr : 0x2ab1eef4c010 len       405504   3168.0 Kb
ptr addr : 0xadb010 len       405632   3169.0 Kb
ptr addr : 0xadb010 len     33656576 262942.0 Kb
ptr addr : 0xadb010 len     33656704 262943.0 Kb
ptr addr : 0x2ab1eef4c010 len     33656832 262944.0 Kb
ptr addr : 0x2ab1eef4c010 len     33656960 262945.0 Kb
```

I do not understand the following :

- Why at some sizes the address value changes and is way greater ?
- Why at allocation size more than 256 Mb it is always the big adress coming out ?

And the question that is related to these code and my main question :

- Why arrays with smaller adresses are faster in access of their data ?
  Faster as 20% faster.

Anyone any clue ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Read up on virtual memory and lazy allocation.